# Run-Time Error 1004 When Using Vlookup with ExecuteExcel4Macro

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, excel-4.0

How do you properly construct a VLOOKUP statement in Excel VBA when using the ExecuteExcel4Macro function in VBA?

I have a function that successfully looks up a value in another excel workbook without opening it using ExecuteExcel4Macro, but when I attempt to change the statement to a VLOOKUP statement I get a Run-time error 1004:

The function:

```
Public Function fGetValueTest(sFilePath, sFileName, sSourceSheet, sSourceCell, vVal, Col)
'Returns the value of a cell from a closed file [BD]

    'Declaring variables [BD]
    Dim sStringMacro As String
    Dim externalValue As Variant
    
    'Setting variables [BD]
    externalValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro("'" & sFilePath & "[" & sFileName & "]" & sSourceSheet & "'!" & _
    Range("A1").Range(sSourceCell).Address(, , xlR1C1))
    
    'Exception error on file not found [BD]
    If Dir(sFilePath & sFileName) = "" Then
        fGetValueTest = "File Not Found!"
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    'If value of source cell is N/A [BD]:
    If Application.IsNA(externalValue) Then
        'Skip and move on [BD]
        fGetValueTest = "0"
    ElseIf IsError(externalValue) Then
        MsgBox "Error - Check fGetValue Function"
    Else
        'Creating macro variable [BD]
        sStringMacro = "'" & sFilePath & "[" & sFileName & "]" & sSourceSheet & "'!" & _
        Range("A1").Range(sSourceCell).Address(, , xlR1C1)
        fGetValueTest = ExecuteExcel4Macro("Vlookup(" & vVal & "," & sStringMacro & "," & Col & ",0)")
        
    End If
    
End Function
```

And it's usage in the subroutine:

```
Sub TestGetValue()

    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim sSourceSheet As String
    Dim sSourceCell As String
    Dim sDestinationCell As String
    Dim sDestinationSheet As String
    Dim vVal As String
    Dim Col As String
    
    sFileName = "0306-0312 Margin Master.xlsx"
    sFilePath = "\\store\GroupDrives\Pricing\_Deli_\Deli Fresh Shift\Margin Master\"
    sSourceSheet = "Bakery"
    sDestinationSheet = "TestSheet"
    sSourceCell = "G10"
    sDestinationCell = "G10"
    vVal = "A10"
    Col = 3
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sDestinationSheet).Range(sDestinationCell) = fGetValueTest(sFilePath, sFileName, sSourceSheet, sSourceCell, vVal, Col)

End Sub
```

I don't see any errors in how the VLOOKUP statement is constructed, does ExecuteExcel4Macro require a different type of statement or is there something else going on here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if anyone happens to know if there is a manual for ExecuteExcel4Macro or any documentation of any real value that would also be helpful!

Comment: Your code seems to be doing a lookup of the string `"A10"` within the single cell range `'\\store\GroupDrives\Pricing\_Deli_\Deli Fresh Shift\Margin Master\[0306-0312 Margin Master.xlsx]Bakery'!G10` and returning the 3rd column of that single cell.  That is going to give errors.

Comment: Sorry, no, it won't be looking for the string `"A10"`, I guess it will be looking for the contents of a cell A10, but I have no idea what cell A10 it will look for - almost certainly not the one in the closed workbook because that would need to be passed as `'\\store\GroupDrives\Pricing\_Deli_\Deli Fresh Shift\Margin Master\[0306-0312 Margin Master.xlsx]Bakery'!R10C1`.  (Why don't you make life easier for yourself and open the other workbook, do whatever processing you need, then close it again?)

Comment: Thanks Yow, I know, making my life easier would be nice.  But in the office here we sometimes have workbooks with tens of thousands of lines, I'm trying to develop a solution that doesn't take 25 minutes to compile information from closed workbooks.  I have adopted the code I was originally attempting to adopt in a different way.  Do I get in trouble on here if I post it as a possible solution?  Well, I'll do it in case it interests you.  It works in it's own way, but I'm still trying to adapt it.  Thanks for leaving the comments!

Comment: Self-answers aren't necessarily bad, although it is best if they could be derived solely on the information in the question.  Your current question reflects two problems (1) the incorrect parameters being passed and (2) the lack of quotation marks around the string being searched for.  The first problem is just "garbage in - garbage out" and can't be fixed without being told what the correct parameters are, but the second problem is something that could be useful to other people.  ...

Comment: I suggest you edit the question to show your updated code **without the     If IsNumeric(vVal) Then ... End If bits** and simply ask "why doesn't this VLookup work".  Then your answer makes complete sense, and the question and answer are useful for other people with a similar problem.  (This is just MY opinion though - other people, including yourself, may disagree.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a possibility if it can be adopted:

Function:

```
Public Function GetVlookup(path, file, sheet, ref, Col, vVal)
'   Retrieves a value from a closed workbook
    Dim arg As String

'   Make sure the file exists
    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
    If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
        GetVlookup = "File Not Found"
        Exit Function
    End If

    If IsNumeric(vVal) Then
      vVal = CDbl(vVal)
    Else
      vVal = Chr(34) & vVal & Chr(34)
    End If
'   Create the argument
    arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & _
      Range(ref).Address(, , xlR1C1)
'   Execute an XLM macro
    GetVlookup = ExecuteExcel4Macro("Vlookup(" & vVal & "," _
     & arg & "," & Col & ",0)")
End Function
```

Subroutine:

```
Sub TestThingSub()
    Dim Varr As Variant
    Varr = GetVlookup("\\store\GroupDrives\Pricing\_Deli_\Deli Fresh Shift\Margin Master\", "0306-0312 Margin Master2.xlsx", "Sheet2", "A1:B26", 2, "HORSE")
    MsgBox Varr
End Sub
```